# gdb: stop values getting optimized

Tags: gdb

while debugging code I see values getting optimized. How should I compile the binary so that these values are always seen and no optimization is done.
eg:

```
(gdb) p  instrument->_line
value has been optimized out
```

or in function stack trace

```
 0x0000000000405a43 in md_test::temp::tempPrint (this=0x61cc50, type=83 'S', sub=<value optimized out>, base=0x0, instrument=<value optimized out>) at temp.cpp:1667
```

Answer (score 0):

> How should I compile the binary so that these values are always seen and no optimization is done.

To completely disable optimization with GCC, use the `-O0` flag at compile time.